# Load js file on mouseover JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is it possible to load js file on some event like `mouseover` or `click`?
I try to load a whole js file not a specific function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example loads the specified js file on `onClick()` event of button

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunction(){

          var file = document.createElement("script");
          file.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
          file.setAttribute("src", "js/js_file.js");
          document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(file);

   }
</script>
```

Similarly, you can also load the js on `onMouseOver()` event of the button or any other HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

**Example using jQuery**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Test</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#myButton').mouseenter(function() {
                        $("head").append($("<script />").prop("type", "text/javascript").prop("src", "http://code.jquery.com/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"));
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="button" id="myButton" value="CLICK" />
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sorry only javascript no jquery